# Error when calling gtk_grid_new()

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, xfce

When I try to run the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxfce4panel/xfce-panel-plugin.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void construct(XfcePanelPlugin *);
static void show_prefs(XfcePanelPlugin *);

XFCE_PANEL_PLUGIN_REGISTER(construct);

static void construct(XfcePanelPlugin *plugin) {
    // Construct a simple gtk eventbox on the panel
    // and add a appropriate sized icon
    GtkWidget *ebox = gtk_event_box_new();
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_size("/usr/share/pixmaps/idea.png", 16, 16, NULL);
    GtkWidget *icon = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);


    // display the previously constructed GTK widgets on the panel
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(plugin), ebox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(ebox), icon);
    gtk_widget_show_all(ebox);
    xfce_panel_plugin_set_expand(XFCE_PANEL_PLUGIN(plugin), TRUE);
    xfce_panel_plugin_menu_show_configure(plugin);
    g_signal_connect(plugin, "configure-plugin", G_CALLBACK(show_prefs), ebox);
}

static void show_prefs(XfcePanelPlugin *plugin) {

    fputs("initializing config dialog...\n", stderr);

    GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(win), 300, 200);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win), "Twittle Preferences");

    GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new();

    gtk_widget_show_all(win);
}
```

The call to `gtk_grid_new()` results in the error

`(wrapper-1.0:26288): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

makefile is available in the gist at https://gist.github.com/fasseg/953c6615e2b0c50ea62c#file-source-L31

Comment: Can you print the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxfce4panel-2.0`? And can you `ldd libtwittle.so` to see if it links to GTK+ as well, and if so, to which file? I'm wondering if something is mixing GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3.

Comment: @andlabs: I added the requested output to the gist at https://gist.github.com/fasseg/953c6615e2b0c50ea62c

Comment: Okay, so there's no GTK+ version mixing going on here; it's GTK+ 3 all around. So why is this happening...

Comment: `GtkWidget` is from GTK2 and `gtk_grid_new()` is from GTK3